# How to hover over multiple table cells?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to make multiple adjacent cells to change colour when one cell is hovered over? And is there a way to make this dynamic (eg. the number of adjacent cells that also change colour can vary)?

*Code below:*

I have a table in React with the following code:

```
<TableBody>
<TableRow>{tableRowGen()}</TableRow>
</TableBody>
```

and the `tableRowGen` function has the following code:

```
const tableRowGen = () => {
    let cells = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < columnNumber; i++) {
      cells.push(
        <TableCell
          className={classes.td}
          onMouseEnter={() => {
            console.log("hi!");
          }}
          align="center"
        >
          {i}
        </TableCell>
      );
    }
    console.log(cells);
    return cells;
  };
```

Currently, I have a class for the table cell (`td`) which changes the hover colour to red:

```
td: {
    ...
    "&:hover": {
      background: "#f00",
    },
  },
```

Example show below:

This is how it is with the current code:

[image]

But is it possible to make 4 and 5 red when hovering only over 3? (as seen below)

[image]

EDIT:
New `tableRowGen` function code:

```
const tableRowGen = () => {
    let cells = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < columnNumber; i++) {
      cells.push(
        <TableCell
          // className={classes.td}
          align="center"
          onMouseEnter={() => onMouseEnter(i)}
          onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
          className={Math.abs(hoveredCell - i) <= 14 ? classes.td : ""}
        >
          {i}
        </TableCell>
      );
    }
    return cells;
  };
```

Other code as per suggestion:

```
const [hoveredCell, setHoveredCell] = React.useState(null);

  const onMouseEnter = React.useCallback((index) => {
    setHoveredCell(index);
  }, []);

  const onMouseLeave = React.useCallback(() => {
    setHoveredCell(null);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way.

Create a separate component that will handle the `hover` event for each `TableRow`.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  highlighted: {
    background: "#f00"
  }
});

const MyTableRow = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const columnNumber = 10;

  // the index of the cell that will trigger if should highlight on hover
  const targetIndex = 3;

  // indeces to highlight
  const indicesToHighlight = [3, 4, 5, 7, 9];

  // when set to true, will highlight
  const [highlight, setHighlight] = React.useState(false);

  function onMouseEnter(event) {
    setHighlight(parseInt(event.target.dataset.index) === targetIndex);
  }

  function onMouseLeave() {
    setHighlight(false);
  }

  const cells = [...Array(columnNumber)].map((_, i) => {
    const shouldHighlighted = indicesToHighlight.includes(i);
    const className = highlight && shouldHighlighted && classes.highlighted;

    return (
      <TableCell key={i} data-index={i} align="center" className={className}>
        {i}
      </TableCell>
    );
  });

  return (
    <TableRow onMouseMove={onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}>
      {cells}
    </TableRow>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit suspicious-thompson-oovo6]

---

Notice that I used `onMouseMove` instead of `onMouseEnter` - `onMouseEnter` will only trigger once when the row is hovered unlike `onMouseMove` it will trigger the `event` each time the mouse pointer is moved.

Also, I don't want to attach the `event listener` on every cell, that would be expensive. I'm using `event delegation` technique, so that only one element will listen the event.

Comment: Thank you for this! Is there a way to not pre-define the indices which will be highlighted, but rather just highlight the adjacent cells (eg. if I hover over 1 then 2 and 3 should also be highlighted or if I hover over 6 then 7 and 8 should be highlighted too)?

Comment: Sure, give me a sec.

Comment: I updated the demo to have `MyTableRowV2` component.

Comment: Thank you! You're a lifesaver.

Comment: Glad I could help 

Comment: @nathvv I removed `highlight` state on `MyTableRowV2` - we can achieve the same result without it. :)

Comment: A bit late, but do you know how to keep each row of those separate? Because right now, if I hover over items in the first row, the colour of the items in the following rows also change?

Comment: You mean, when you hover over the first row - then hover on the second row, you want the first row to maintain its color/hover state?

Comment: Not really. Rather I want just the first row items to change colour while the following rows remain the same. Because right now, if you hover over the first row at index 3, then all of the rows at index 3 will change colour. Could I make each row independent?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand. When I hover over any of the row at index 3; index 3, 4 and 5 of that row only changes its color https://oovo6.csb.app/

Comment: Sorry for bothering, turns out it was a problem with how I dynamically made my rows. Thanks!

Comment: Ohh haha no proble :D

Answer (score 1):

You could definitely do this with javascript, adding or removing css classes when the user hovers. It's also possible to do this type of thing using only css with a [sibling selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp). Here is a simple example:

```css
td:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

td:hover + td {
  background-color: red;
}

td:hover + td + td {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1,1</td>
      <td>1,2</td>
      <td>1,3</td>
      <td>1,4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2,1</td>
      <td>2,2</td>
      <td>2,3</td>
      <td>2,4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

This is the static version - if you want to make the number of cells dynamic, you will need to use javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately, static might be too difficult to implement for my use case, and so using java script is the best way to go here. However, I don't quite know to approach it - I have updated my original post with suggestions from the other answer, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS it's only possible to highlight cells next to the hovered:

```css
td:hover, td:hover + td {
  background-color: red;
}
```

So most likely you have to use JS to do it. In this case you have to detect hover.
Then you need to determine cells to be highlighted based on `hoveredCell`. For example you want to only highlight directly adjacent ones. And you should add class if the cell satisfy the condition:

```
const [hoveredCell, setHoveredCell] = useState<number | null>(null);

const onMouseEnter = React.useCallback((index) => {
    setHoveredCell(index);
}, []);

const onMouseLeave = React.useCallback(() => {
    setHoveredCell(null);
}, []);

<TableCell
  onMouseEnter={() => onMouseEnter(index)}
  onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
  className={Math.abs(hoveredCell - index) <= 1 ? classes.hovered : ''}
>
```

Condition: `Math.abs(hoveredCell - index) <= 1` can be extracted as a function on `hoveredCell` and `index` and be customized via props. Or you can just change `1` to whatever number of cells

Comment: I have done what you have said, but it doesn't seem to be working, would you be able to see what I may have done wrong? I have edited my original post to reflect the changes.